# Database relationships for a flagging system in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, database, laravel, laravel-5

## Problem

I'm building an application where are many things a user can flag. Lets take these example things a user can flag:

- Another user
- An image
- A comment
- A tag

So I want one flagging table to deal with flagging all these things, but with my vision and to stick to Laravel's conventions so I can make use of relationship methods, I'd have to do something like this for the `flags` table...

---

## My "solution"

```
+----+---------+----------+--------+------------+-----------------------------+
| id | user_id | image_id | tag_id | comment_id | message                     |
+----+---------+----------+--------+------------+-----------------------------+
| 1  | 3       | null     | null   | null       | I'm building an application |
+----+---------+----------+--------+------------+-----------------------------+
| 2  | null    | 45       | null   | null       | This image is NSFW!         |
+----+---------+----------+--------+------------+-----------------------------+
| 3  | null    | null     | 234    | null       | Tag includes bad content... |
+----+---------+----------+--------+------------+-----------------------------+
| 4  | null    | null     | null   | 125        | Spamming!!!                 |
+----+---------+----------+--------+------------+-----------------------------+
```

Now this way, this flagging system is not scalable at all! If I want to be able to flag things in the future, I'd have to add a column and map it etc.

I don't like this messy solution and I can't think of another Laravel-y way to do this!

---

I need to figure out a scalable way to handle flags with one table for multiple things in a Laravel 5.2 way.

Comment: I'd consider a [polymorphic relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations). A `flags` table with `user_id`, `message`, `flaggable_id`, and `flaggable_type`. The last column there would indicate which table it belongs to. Eloquent makes this real easy to work with.

Comment: You didn't think of creating a table called `entity_types` where you can **add** rows with values such as `user`, `image`, `tag`, `comment` and then instead of having X columns, you have reference to `entity.id` and another column that holds the value? There's nothing Laravel-y about this design, Laravel is there to help you, not to enforce something weird and hard just for the sake of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should take a look at polymorphic relations: https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many-polymorphic-relations

You create a table for `flags` and a table called `flaggable`.  Flaggable has the columns `id`, `flag_id`, `flaggable_type`, and `flaggable_id`.  Then an entry might be

`1 | 1 (id of the flag) | App\Image (type of flaggable) | 45 (ID of image)`

Comment: This is precisely what the OP needs.